# yii2 advanced login function always returns invalid username and password

Tags: yii2

I made no changes in yii login function but it returns error while giving correct username and password

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->render('index');
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more code, we need the rest of the code involved as well.

Comment: It would be nice to know if you modified LoginForm.php and User.php inside the models folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
```

instead `return $this->render('index');`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. For advanced template default signup scenario you need to activate your account by email confirmation (the email you provided at the time of signup). Until that moment your status is inactive. This status is used for login - only active users can log in.

If you're using this project for local purposes, you may change the status of your record in db table 'user' from 9(inactive) to 10(active). Then you will be able to login.

Answer (score 0):

may me problem inside your user model, check validatePassword Or findByUser functions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).